# SQL or R delete rows and separate by type

Tags: sql, r, database

I have the following issue in `SQL`, but would gladly like to find out how to solve this issue in `R` language.

I have 2 different tables:

Table 1 - annonymizedData

```
 userID     AssigID   Score   Time on Task
 12345      10001      4      60
 12346      10001      5      70
 12567      10003      9      80
 12789      10003      8      67
 12903      10004      7      73
```

Table 2 Anonymized users

```
 userID     Teacher   
 12345      False  
 12346      False    
 12567      False    
 12789      False     
 12903      True
```

Table 3 Assignments

```
 AssigID   type  
 10001      1   
 10001      1    
 10003      2   
 10003      2     
 10004      3
```

What I am trying to do is:

- Delete the rows from Table 1 where users are teachers,so if the value teacher from table two is true based on userID I want to get rid of those users in table 1.
- Build a query to see the data from the table 1 where assignments are type 1, so I somehow need to connect the type value from the table 3?

Or perhaps if someone knows how to do this in R would be great too.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is.  You should be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for first point:

```
delete Table1 from Table1 
join Table2  on
Table1.userID = Table2.userID and
Table2.Teacher   = true
```

Solution for Point 2

```
select table1.* from table1 
join table3 on
table1.AssigID  =   table3.AssigID   and
table3.type     =   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am interpreting the question as simply the `delete`, because that is what is in the title.

You can easily do the `delete` in SQL.  The exact syntax might vary a bit by database, but it looks something like this:

```
delete data d
    where d.userID = (select u.userId from users u where u.teacher = 'true');
```

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper . . . I'm impressed at your powers of deduction, but I don't see what in the question implies an outer join, much less a right outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` in R, join all the tables together and filter out the teachers:

```
table1 %>% 
  inner_join(table2, by = "userID") %>% 
  inner_join(table3, by = "AssigID") %>% 
  filter(Teacher == "False")

  userID AssigID Score Time_on_Task Teacher type
1  12345   10001     4           60   False    1
2  12345   10001     4           60   False    1
3  12346   10001     5           70   False    1
4  12346   10001     5           70   False    1
5  12567   10003     9           80   False    2
6  12567   10003     9           80   False    2
7  12789   10003     8           67   False    2
8  12789   10003     8           67   False    2
```